# Expected function to return very few rows, but returns all rows

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgis

I am creating a Postgres/postgis function that is suppose to cut an input-geometry according to a 'hard-coded' table's geometry. The hard-coded table is called `j.borders`  and its geometry attribute is called `geom`. If the input-geometry intersects several geometries (rows) from `j.borders`, `j.borders` geometry is collected into one geometry (using st_union), which is then used to cut the input-geometry using st_difference. If the input-geometry doesn't intersects  `j.borders` geometry, the input-geometry is returned un-modified.

The function I have created behaves as i want it to, however:
**I dont understand why it behaves like this**

the function in question:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.clip_geom(
    IN in_geom geometry,
    OUT out_geom geometry)
-- can be called like SELECT public.clip_geom(geom) FROM a_table

  RETURNS geometry AS
$BODY$
BEGIN

    SELECT 
    st_multi( -- st_multi makes sure the geometry is always the same "type"
    COALESCE(
    ST_DIFFERENCE(in_geom,st_union(brdr.geom)), -- cutting the geometry 
    in_geom -- not cutting the geometry
    )) 
    INTO out_geom  
    FROM j.borders brdr
    WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(in_geom, brdr.geom); -- if the two geometries intersects 

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

If you give this function a table of 5 rows with geometry and 2 of them intersects the border-geometry,  it then returns all 5 rows, where 2 have been clipped to the border.

the select statement is followed by a where-clause which states the input-geometry and border-geometry have to intersect. If the two geometries do not intersect, nothing is returned, correct?
**but why does the function then return the unmodified geometry?** Does it have something to do with the `COALESCE`?

Comment: st_union is usually an aggregate function, but you have no GROUP BY. It apparently [also supports](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Union.html) being called with a single array argument, which I suppose is why you're not getting the error message complaining about using an aggregate function without GROUP BY; if it ends up being NULL, I would assume the ST_DIFFERENCE would also evaluate to NULL, thus falling through to the 2nd item in the coalesce. BTW, unless you're planning to add more functionality to this function, it does not need PL/pgsql - a LANGUAGE SQL function should be fine.

Comment: Oh, ignore me. You select no other columns, so you shouldn't need a GROUP BY, even if using an aggregate function. (the LANGUAGE SQL point still stands though)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @AdamKG!